# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') while pushing an item in an object key-value initialized as array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, frontend

So I'm trying to put some value in the 'Images' key (which is initialized as an array) but when I'm using the push function to achieve so its giving me the above error.

Here is the object:

```
let post_data = useRef(
        {
            Title: "",
            Content: "",
            Course: "",
            Year: 1,
            Documents:[{
                Name: "test",
                URL:"test"
            }, {
                Name: "hey",
                URL: "Hey"
                }],
            Images: [],
        });
```

Here is the code causing the error:

```
<input accept='.pdf, .docx, .ppt, .png, .jpg' multiple="multiple" onChange={(e) =>
                            {
                                if (e.target.files[0])
                                {
                                    let str = "";
                                    
                                    
                                    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        post_data.Images.push("test");
                                        if (i == (e.target.files.length) - 1)
                                        {
                                            str += e.target.files[i].name;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        str += e.target.files[i].name +"," +" ";
                                    }
                                    
                                    console.log(post_data);
                                    setFileName(str);
                                    
                                }
                            }} id="dropzone-file" type="file" class="hidden" />
```

I tried pushing a string in an object's key which is of array datatype onChange of a file Upload using react. I was expecting my object to look something like
Images:["test1", "test2"]
. However, the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')" occured.

I apologize for any confusion my language may cause. English is not my first language, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes.

Comment: where you using the push? The error saying that you can't push to undefined value.

Comment: @sushildlh The first line in the for loop.

Comment: Your `post_data.Images` is undefined. do `console.log(post_data)` and look? what is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
post_data.current.Images.push("test");
```

`useRef` is used for the persist variable, which our normal variable can't do that. Always use `ref` value with the help of `current` properties.

**Note: Also make your useRef variable as `const`.**